# Problem When Dealing with Inputs in React Array State

Tags: reactjs, arraylist, react-hooks

I was trying to create a dynamic CV App where you can add multiple forms and each form should display its values seperately but I stumbled into a problem when working with array states.

here is my code:

```
  function App() {

  const [inputs, setinputs] = React.useState([])
  const [output, setOutput] = React.useState([])

  function Input(props){
    return (
      <div className='form'>
        <input
        type="text"
        id='name'
        name = "name"
        value = {props.name}
        placeholder="Name"
        onChange={props.handleChange}
        />
        <input
        type="text"
        id='age'
        name = "age"
        value = {props.age}
        placeholder="Age"
        onChange={props.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }

  function handlechange(e){
    setOutput([
      ...output,
      {
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      }
    ])
  }

  function addInput(){
    setinputs([
      ...inputs,
      <Input
      name={output.name}
      age = {output.age}
      handleChange={handlechange}
      />
    ])

  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      <div className='inputs'>
        <h2>Inputs:</h2>
      {inputs}
      </div>
      

        <button
        onClick={addInput}
        >Add Input</button>

      <div className='outputs'>
      <h2>Outputs:</h2>

        {output.map(item => {
          return (
            <div className='card'>
            <h1>Name: {item.name}</h1>
            <h4>Age: {item.age}</h4>
            </div>
            
          )
          
        })}
      </div>

    </div>
  );
}
```

The first problem that I encountered with my code is that when chnaging the value of one input it overwrites the value of the other one:

here it first displayed John but then after adding the age, the name was gone

[First case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SI0o9.png)

The second problem is when I add multiple input forms their values start to entangle rather than having a display Card for each seperate input form.

[Second case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JCmQ.png)

PS: this only happens when I add multiple input forms and then I proceed to fill them. When I add them one by one after filling the first one this doesn't happen but of course the first problem with the age is the same

[Third Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAQUm.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to look into React Hook Form library. It really helps working with forms in React. It might look a bit complicated in the beginning, but believe me you'll be grateful you went for it.

Here is the [link](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usefieldarray/) to documentation where they show how to do what you need.